# jquery do somethingS when a checkbox is checked not working

Tags: jquery, if-statement, checkbox

i have this

```
$("input:checkbox").live("click", function() {
    if(this.checked){
    $(this).next().show();
    $(this).prev().css('color','red');}
    else{
    $(this).next().hide();
    $(this).prev().css('color','black');}
});
```

but jquery doesn't not apply all the commands nested in IF statement ! it executes only the last one !

```
$(this).prev().css('color','red');
```

and ignores all the other commands !
i want when i click on the checkbox to do a list of things ! and not only just one ! how can i make that work please

Comment: `.on` is the official replacement for `.live`  See http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: can you provide us your markup? it seems the `.next()` element isn't able to be shown (maybe `<br/>` or something)

Answer (score 0):

I believe your next element can't be shown in this way, like a `<br/>`

For example in this code

```
<input type="checkbox"/>
<br/>
<a style="display:none;">test</a>
```

the `<a>` won't appear, because with `.next()` you're matching the `<br/>`
( http://jsfiddle.net/bukfixart/SgGEZ/ )

Comment: when i put the first like only !  `$(this).next().show();`  it works ! so jquery handles the next() element with no problems !